# Implement Picasa in Android

Tags: android, mobile, picasa

I'm trying to retrieve albums in an Android application. Well, I suppose that I can't  use:

```
PicasawebService myService = new PicasawebService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
myService.setUserCredentials("liz@gmail.com", "mypassword");
```

Inside the [link](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java?hl=nl-NL).

So I try to implement with some samples that i found in the web, but some classes was missing:

```
import com.google.api.services.picasa.PicasaClient;
import com.google.api.services.picasa.PicasaUrl;
import com.google.api.services.picasa.model.AlbumEntry;
import com.google.api.services.picasa.model.UserFeed;
```

So I imagine that I need to construct my own like [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/shared/gdata/shared-sample-picasa/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/picasa/?repo=samples&r=97e6060623a400769dfaa72dbe20e66e00a81620).

I don't know if you know a way to do this more simple or a way to integrate picasa by another way.

Please tell me if I'm in the right way.

Thanks

Comment: I think, Android synchronizes itself with your picasa album.  You should be able to access your picasa images using [MediaStore.Images.Media](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, really exist a few information about this.

But i find a simple solution using normal http requests. Here's the link:

http://rcs34-android.blogspot.com/2012/09/connect-to-picasa-album-from-android.html

and check too the Picasa Developer References.

If want to upload a picture is simple too. Use something like multipart and in a few lines will be work.

Also can check the code in gdata, to get a few knowladge about the structure and how you can implement it.

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/Dependencies

Thanks to RCS-34 for a simple solution.